# Handling when XML datasource for a gridview is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview, datasource

I have an `xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data>
  <entry entrydatetime="22.09.2014 11:20">
    <location>Test</location>
    <date>22.09.2014</date>
    <time>11:30</time>
    <description>Hello World!</description>
    <entrymadeby>Testuser</entrymadeby>
    <priority>High</priority>
  </entry>
</data>
```

I successfully connected this `XML` file to a `gridview` and it works fine. But what if there is an empty `xml` file like the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data>
  <entry></entry>
</data>
```

The `XML` file in this state won't work together with my programm / `gridview` because it doesn't find the right rows. How can I customize my `gridview` that it just shows the header row but without `DataRows` ?

Of course, i could write a method which validates my `XML` file, but is there an easier or "cleaner" way to realize that ?

Answer (score 1):

you can just add this attribut in your gridview : `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"`
when your datasource is empty only your header will show up